# Lines are visible only on the 1st page

Tags: jasper-reports

Here is my detail band:

```
<detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{antibioResult}]]></printWhenExpression>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="1" y="1" width="798" height="19" forecolor="#172983" uuid="d6dabfde-0ea9-4b6b-83c4-b557815cedee">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <subreportParameter name="binary_id">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{binary_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["bacreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <line>
            <reportElement style="borderLine" stretchType="ContainerHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="20" uuid="d5cb2ecc-f71a-4a3c-8d27-7be4c5a86da5">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
        <line>
            <reportElement style="borderLine" stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="800" y="0" width="1" height="20" uuid="08e46ff8-8a65-406b-9164-a6737baa022e">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
    </band>
</detail>
```

And here is BorderLine style:

```
    <style name="borderLine" forecolor="#172983"/>
```

Two lines are visible only in 1st page and not visible in others.
How to fix that?

UPD: It's looks like the lines is not drawn after page break. So how to stretch those line to the whole subreport to several pages?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: set "Details Overflows" flag to the Line element.